# Remove $ sign from sheet name in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, windows-forms-designer, oledbconnection

I am using Excel Sheet to process data,

```
DataTable dtSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
var sheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
        ("Select * FROM [sheet = "+sheetName+"]",connection);

using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    string sqlConnectionString = MyConString;
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
        bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Temp";
        bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
        MessageBox.Show("Upload to DB Temp Table Successful!");
    }
}
```

As you can in the first two lines of code I gave here, I am using OLEDBSchemaTable method to get the name of the first sheet in excel.
this function get the sheet name but along with it puts a "$" sign at the end of sheet name. for example my excel first sheet name is """Sheet1""", then in code its get sheet1 and puts a $ sign at end. eg """Sheet1$""".. 
Please help me to remove that $ sign or give me another method to get the sheet name.

Comment: Altough this is a great question title... you should really put more describing titles for your questions

Comment: `var sheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Replace("$",string.Empty);` do this and it should work

Comment: NIcoRiff...I will keep it in mind next time .. Thank you.

Comment: MethodMan.. Just going to try, will let you know.

Comment: @RizwanAzam just [edit] the question including its title.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the '$' character from your string with `String.Replace`:

```
var newName = sheetName.Replace('$', '');
```